# Jquery Tablesorter with stickyheaders ... Lines thru the header

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have implemented the "Stickyheaders" option of the table sorter.  It works Great!

However, where I work the force IE back to IE7 (I have no control over that).  What I noticed is that when I am running IE7 the headers have lines running thru them (it looks like its the cell boarder ghosting).    These lines go away once you start to scroll.
[image]

These lines also do not appear in Chrome or IE 8 and above.

Is there anyway I can fix these lines for when running IE 7?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by your work forces IE back to IE7?  What's the logic behind this?  Most sites around the web won't even support IE7?

Comment: As a test I ran stackoverflow.com in IE compatibility mode as IE7 and it doesn't even render correctly.  So it doesn't make sense to me that you can even post messages to this site under IE7?

Comment: The application I work on is part of a state agency web site.  For some reason they have set up IIS to force IE down to version 7.  When Not logged into that web site, ie goes back up to "11 or Edge"  (I used the "developer tools" to determine the browser version.       PS.  I use Chrome to post to this site note IE, it works better.

Comment: Why the down vote?  Just because I am forced to write an IE7 compatible web site?  That seems a little unfair.

Comment: I also work on a state agency website and years ago we had this problem for intranet applications in IE where it would force intranet sites into compatibility mode (you can see this in Compatibility View Settings).  Anyhow, we fixed this using meta tags in the header. 
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">`
`<meta charset="utf-8">`

Comment: for the record, I'm not the one who downvoted you.  It's possible you were downvoted for not posting code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work around this, use the following meta tags in your header.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

If you need a detailed description of why this works, read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/what-does-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-do).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @user9263373  That did the trick.   This is just an FYI for those that use master pages.  You can add the Meta tag this way ...

```
 HtmlMeta tag = new HtmlMeta();
 tag.HttpEquiv = "X-UA-Compatible";
 tag.Content = "IE=edge,chrome=1";  
 Header.Controls.AddAt(0, tag);'
```

Notice the "AddAt", the Meta tag needs to be the first tag in the Header.